# error while Retrieving the subquery column in where condition to main query

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to retrieve a column in sub query which is used in where condition in Oracle SQL.  I am facing ORA-00904 invalid identifier error. Below is the query. Can someone please resolve.

trying to retrieve ev.type , ev.fil_path in the sub-query select ev.type , ev.fil_path,ev.test_path from effortvariation ev

I tried giving alias , but not accepted.

```
select
   ev.fil_path,
   ev.tes_path,
   sp.uname,
   sp.pwd,
   s.desc,
   sp.option,
   oq.master_id,
   oq.status
from onlineQuery oq

inner join supporttask s

    on oq.sq =s.seq

inner join securityports sp

   on sp.sq=oq.sq

where sp.type in 
             (select ev.type , ev.fil_path,ev.test_path from effortvariation ev
             where ev.team =
                        (select team from allTeams where id ='k238')
             and ev.name ='qa'
              )
and sp.acct='active'
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read, and to write.

Comment: @jarlh,can you pl chk now

Comment: Much better! The subquery is supposed to return only one column, the one to be matched with sp.type. (I'd guess ev.type.)

Comment: ok, i tried removing the other two columns from the sub-qry and tried to put that in main qry for retrieval. I mean i dint change the main qry select column. Still i saw the same error. Suggust plz

Comment: The subquery result can only be used in the IN comparison with sp.type. Nothing from the WHERE clause can be used in the SELECT list.

Comment: ohh ok, Any other go/option.

Comment: Move the subquery, with all its returned columns, to the FROM clause, JOIN it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220943/discussion-between-inspiron-and-jarlh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the subquery, with all its returned columns, to the `FROM` clause, and `JOIN` it.

```
select
   ev.fil_path,
   ev.tes_path,
   sp.uname,
   sp.pwd,
   s.desc,
   sp.option,
   oq.master_id,
   oq.status
from onlineQuery oq

inner join supporttask s

    on oq.sq =s.seq

inner join securityports sp

   on sp.sq=oq.sq

INNER JOIN
             (select type , fil_path,test_path from effortvariation
             where team =
                        (select team from allTeams where id ='k238')
             and name ='qa'
              ) ev ON ev.type = sp.type
WHERE sp.acct='active'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used SQL*Plus, it would point to *exact* place where error happened. For example:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from employee
  3  where 1 = 1
  4    and id = 23;
  and id = 23
      *                                 --> see? ID is invalid
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier
```

`ORA-00904` *usually* means that column with such a name doesn't exist in that table. So, if I change it to a column whose name is valid:

```
SQL> c/id/empno
  4*   and empno = 23
SQL> /

no rows selected

SQL>
```

No more errors (OK, nothing has been returned, but that's not an *error*).

I suggest you do the same, find what's wrong, check the table, fix column name. We could assist if we knew tables' descriptions, but - we don't, you never posted that info.

Comment: Nice use of `c/` in SQLPlus!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from onlineQuery oq --your_columns
 inner join supporttask s
  on oq.sq=s.seq
 inner join securityports sp
  on sp.sq=oq.sq
where exists 
(select 1 from effortvariation ev 
 inner join allteams t
  on ev.team=t.team
where ev.name='qa' and t.id='k238')
and sp.acct='active'
```